# Abrir fichero de sistema en kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo abrir mediante un formato semejante al de tkinter filedialog askopenfile usando el framework de kivy. He visto que se usa el filechooser en sus versiones list y Icon, si no hay otra alternativa, ¿Como puedo hacer una ventana emergente a partir de un boton que gestione un elemento de este tipo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solucion utilizando el elemento filechooser, el cual posee un evento on_selection y la propiedad selection, de esta manera he logrado sacar la ruta de un archivo cuando clico sobre él. La solucion en kivy sería:

```
FileChooserIconView:
    id:filechooser
    path: root.defaultPath
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb:[.2,.2.,.2]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_selection: root.selectedPath = filechooser.selection[0]
```